# Get data without knowing fieldname in codeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, get, field

I am totally new to CodeIgniter.

Suppose I have a User Table as follows:

`ID|NAME|PASS | ...`

`1 |n1__|p1xxx| ...`

`2 |n2__|p2xxx| ...`

`..|....|.....| ...`

To show it in the HTML table, I should query first get all data in table User, then I call it in my User_Controller to pass `$data['users']` to my view.

In a ordinary way, we should know all of the field name in order to get the specific field. For instance:

```
 <?php if (count($users)): foreach ($users as $user): ?>    
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $user->id; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user->name; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user->pass; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user->...; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user->...; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; endif; ?>
```

It is such a frustrated way if we are dealing with hundreds of fields.

My question is simple. Could we code without mentioning -> id, ->name , ->pass, ..? 
I guess we could use a nested `foreach`. However, I failed to find how to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a good luck at what codeigniter calls the HTML Table Class 
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/table.html

It will do exactly what you want - **take a result from a database and display it as a table - without having to name the fields** !

```
  // Always use active record when possible
  // this will return all fields and records 
  if( $data['users'] = $this->db->get('users');  ) {
  // Load your view 
 }

  // In the view 
  $this->load->library('table');
  echo $this->table->generate($users);
```

And it will do a lot more, look at the documentation for more detailed examples. Combine it with a little CSS and you can create very complex Data Tables with just a little code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a nested loop to go through the result:

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM user');

foreach($query->result() as $result){
    foreach($result as $key => $value){
        //key will be the field name and value will be 
        //the content of the field
        echo $key . ' - ' . $value .'<br>';
    }
}
```

This would print out something like

```
ID - 1
NAME - n1__
PASS - p1xxx
ID - 2
NAME - n2__
PASS - p2xxx
```

based on your example table (with the fields you posted obviously -- if there are more fields, they would be included).

Comment: I've  re-coded as you recommend. But, I face a little bit problem.

`<?php if (count($users))`

`{ echo '<tr>';`

` foreach ($users->result() as $result) { `

        foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
            //key will be the field name and value will be 
            //the content of the field
            echo ' <td> ' . $value . '</td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    </tr>';
}
else {
echo '
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">We could not find any users.</td>
    </tr>
    ';
} ?>`

The error is :  Call to a member function result() on a non-object. Could you help me?

Comment: There is a problem with the query or you're not using the db class. `->result()` works on an object returned from a query generated using `$this->db`. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html